# Fancybox2 modify loaded content

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to change a css values once a page is loaded by an AJAX call with FancyBox 2.
My goal is to hide a block in the loaded page (only when loaded by the AJAX call of FancyBox).
I guess somehow it is possible to use the Afterload method.

Someone got a clue??

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.fancybox.update();` method (inside the `afterLoad` callback) to re-size fancybox to match the size (`width` and `height`) of the content inside of it.